# Unwind segue doesn't work in Swift 3 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, unwind-segue

I'm trying to test unwind segue in iOS 10 and Swift 3.

I made a simple app like this:
[image]

[image]

I add code for segue in `TableViewController` class and connect "Cancel" button and Exit on Table View Controller Scene:

```
@IBAction func unwindToRootViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Unwind to Root View Controller")
}
```

but my simple segue doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you add a _ before `segue` like so: `@IBAction func unwindToRootViewController(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue)` (and then you might have to reconnect your segue in Interface Builder)

Comment: @pbodsk I try both: `_segue` and `_ segue` and it doesn't work. My educational project with same problem: https://github.com/IlyaGutnikov/SwiftStoryBoardsTutorial

Comment: Oh...I just noticed that you said that you had added code for the segue in your `TableViewController`, shouldn't it be in the "outer" `ViewController`? (have a look here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/)

Comment: @pbodsk Yes, you are right. I had to add segue code to my `ViewController`. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'll take the liberty of adding an answer with the result, OK?

Comment: @pbodsk Of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As can be seen in the comments above the problem was this:

> I add code for segue in TableViewController class

The unwind segue has to be in your "outer" `ViewController`, not the `TableViewController`.

[This article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) gives a very nice introduction to unwind segues.

Comment: I was porting some working objc code to swift and none of my unwind segue's worked.  Your first comment in the question above was the solution to my problem as I was missing the "_" in my method signatures. Sometimes single character errors are the most difficult to find. Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome and yes sometimes you spend hours on a problem and the solution ends out being a single character added in juuuust the right place...programming eh ¯\_(ツ)_/¯